# FoxPro and Internet Explorer 10

Tags: internet-explorer, automation, click

I have problems with Internet Explorer API.
Earlier I used to connect, authorize, and press the button on the site using

```
ie = CREATEOBJECT("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.navigate('site')
ie.document.all("login").value = login
ie.document.all("password").value = password
ie.document.all("auth").click
```

Now this site didn't support Internet Explorer or, rather, didn't support compatibility settings of IE.

When compatibility settings turned on I can authorize using this way, but can't click scripts (even manually) after, when compatibility settings off I cant authorize and manually click.

Tell me, please, another way to open explorer, read content, filling fields and clicking on the buttons and script links?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this as follows:

```
IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.navigate("site")
IE.Visible = .t.

Do While IE.readystate <> 4
enddo

IE.document.getElementbyId("login").focus(1) && Mark the parameter, can be anything, no matter what.
IE.document.getElementbyId("login").value = "login"
IE.document.getElementbyId("password").value = "password"
IE.document.getElementbyId("auth").click(1)  && Mark the parameter, can be anything, no matter what.
```

Alternative:
ie.document.forms(0).submit(1)  && 0 in forms() is site dependend
ie.document.forms(0).elements(4).click(1)  && 4th element is site dependend

There is no documentation on the parameter (1) and only VFP seems to need is since IE9. And any value or type will do.

Comment: I'v just tried this. When compatibility settings turned off, Internet Explorer doesn't support "getElementbyId".

Comment: Do You know, can I open browser using CREATEOBJECT("Wscript.Shell") and then click some button on webpage, or do the same with CREATEOBJECT('HYPERLINK')?

Comment: My answer is not about GetElementbyID but about the (1) parameter in click(1). That solves your problem. If GetElementbyID doesn't work that's because the specific site doesnt allow this way of access. If ie.document.all("login").value works for you that;s fine. Alternative you can use forms(#x).Elements(#y)